# SQlite error: "no such table "

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am currently building a simple bank program in Ruby. I have set it up MVC style. I am getting the following error message.

```
/home/devil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': no such table: managers (SQLite3::SQLException)
from /home/devil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
from /home/devil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
from /home/devil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
from /home/devil/Desktop/RubyBank-manager_model/model.rb:19:in `initialize_database'
from /home/devil/Desktop/RubyBank-manager_model/model.rb:7:in `initialize'
from controller.rb:8:in `new'
from controller.rb:8:in `initialize'
from controller.rb:124:in `new'
from controller.rb:124:in `<main>'
```

Earlier in the day the program was working fine. I changed a local variable's name in a controller method and it started to throw me the above error.

Things I have tried that have failed:

- Update my SQlite gem files to the latest version.
- Revert to previous commits from my GitHub that worked and tried to run the program.
- Revert ONLY the local variable method in question back to it's former functioning name.
- Googling to my heart's content.

SEE MY GITHUB FOR PROGRAM CODE: https://github.com/erikasland/RubyBank/tree/add_manager

Comment: You should post the portion of your Ruby code which are making the database call, rather than forcing everyone to dig through GitHub.

Comment: When you run `sqlite3 bank.db` from the command line and execute `.tables`, does `managers` show up?

Comment: Amadan, this is what I get it I run that command: 

`devil@DEVil:~/repos/ruby_bank$ sqlite3 bank.db
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables;
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "tables;". Enter ".help" for help
sqlite> 
`

Comment: 1) If you want to get someone's attention, use the `@` sign (`@Amadan`); I accidentally returned, or I wouldn't have read your reply. (questioner and answerer are automatically notified about their comments, so I don't need to tag you.) 2) `.tables`, not `.tables;`, without the semicolon, as it is SQLite3 command and not a SQL one; but glad Sculper could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was created in [this](https://github.com/erikasland/RubyBank/commit/3dcef98ae531c7564b89dc2f2aa5c0572822521f) commit, on line 19 of `model.rb`.  You're attempting to check if a table exists by selecting from it:

```
managers_exist = db.execute("SELECT * FROM managers").length > 0
```

This can be solved by querying against the schema, rather than the table - you've successfully done this with your `accounts` table:

```
accounts_table_exists = db.execute("SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE 
      type='table' AND name= ?", "accounts").length > 0
```

Notice that you're selecting from `sqlite_master`, not `accounts`.  What you want is something like this:

```
managers_exist= db.execute("SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE 
      type='table' AND name= ?", "managers").length > 0
```

However, it seems to me that a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` approach might be the solution you're actually looking for.